# How can I devote separated session for different pages?

Tags: php, session, captcha

I have following script which generates a captcha:

```
// captcha.php
session_start();
$captcha_token='';
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){$captcha_token .= rand(0,9).' ';}
$_SESSION['captcha'] = str_replace(" ","",$captcha_token);

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(110, 34);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 245, 245, 245);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 80, 80, 80);
imagestring($im, 8, 15, 9, $captcha_token, $text_color);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Also I have multiple pages which need a captcha. I use `captcha.php` for all of them. Something like this:

```
// contact.php
<input name="captcha" type="text" />
<img  src="captcha.php" />

// resend_password.php
<input name="captcha" type="text" />
<img  src="captcha.php" />

// multiple_wrong_login.php
<input name="captcha" type="text" />
<img  src="captcha.php" />
```

All fine. Just as you see there is just one session `$_SESSION['captcha']` for all scripts. And when I open `contact.php` and immediately after that `resend_password.php`, then the *captcha* in the `contact.php` will be invalid. How can I fix it? I mean how can I make a separated captcha for different pages?

Comment: each session should just overwrite the last,

Comment: @Dagon emm, what do you mean *"the last"*?

Comment: you are reusing the same code, which writes the same session variable, so what ever value was last set\seen should be correct

Comment: @Dagon Yes currently my script works as you said. But I want to devote different session variables for different pages. Actually I want multiple valid captcha.

Comment: well if it works as is, then why

Comment: @Dagon Because it works imperfect. When I open `contact.php`, and then `resend_password.php`, then the captcha in `contact.php` will be expire, because always there is *one* valid captcha. That's not what I want. I what each page has its own captcha.

Comment: if your on  resend_password.php you dont need the contact.php captcha, just the resend_password.php one

Comment: @Dagon Yes actually that's correct, the possibility of having need to two different pages which have captcha is pretty low. But still I think that would be more standard if I have two separated valid captcha for `contact.php` and `resend_password.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my suggestion:

parse a variable to the captcha script like so:

```
<img  src="captcha.php?page=resend_password" />
```

then in the script:

```
$_SESSION['captcha'][$_GET['page']] = str_replace(" ","",$captcha_token);
```

Comment: Hmm .. that's not bad ..! thank you, upvote.  But do you think having separated sessions for different pages is better or should I just have one session for all pages? What's better in your opinion?

Comment: what do you think that discussion above was about? i clearly think this is pointless, but you insisted it was what you wanted to do so ...

Comment: Ok .. seems you are right and doing this is pointless. I will not follow your suggestion in this answer *(also thanks for the advice)*. anyway at least I know **how** can I do that if I want `:-)`